# How to store and make changes to a database within a Chrome Extension?

Tags: javascript, database, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm currently working on a Chrome Extension which searches for specific content within webpages.

Now, my idea is to build a Database based on the correctness of this search result (which would be verified by the users), so it can be more accurate in these searches as the database grows. Kind of like a Machine Learning process I guess.

I'm fairly new to programming and I would like your advice on what are the best possible ways to do this.

Currently I just have JS/HTML/CSS, and it seems to me that I'm gonna need some other language.

A single CSV that the Extension could read/write would be enough for this, I think. Or something with SQL.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You have to compose and post a CRUD command to a web server page (a server you own or you controll)
That page can be written in php, asp.net..
Web server page receive the CRUD command and run the relevant statement on your database via OBCD driver (or other similar driver)
Normally the web server page then responds, as a result of your post, with a message (text, xml, json) that makes you understand if the command has been successfully executed or not.

**EDIT 04/30/2021 16:24 Rome Timezone**

you say:

> which would be verified by the users

what did you mean exactly?

more users together contributes to make the shared database better ?

or every single user contribute by itself to make his own database better ?

if one then my previous answer could be a good start point.

if two, forget my previos answer a think to build a indexedDB within your extension.

Comment: It would be the same Database for all users.

Isn't there a simpler way, like making a public file somehow and accessing it through XMLHttpRequest?

Answer (score 0):

Read a csv or txt file through XMLHttpRequest is not a problem, but how do you thing to write the same file with the same tool (XHR) ?

You could think about a Google public spreadsheet.

"Google Sheets" allows you through an "endpoint url" and a set of API to insert new rows\records and to read the entire content of the spreadsheet
or (if I remember correctly) part of its content.

I state that it's now 2 years or maybe more since I got interested in Google Sheets.
Based on the information in my possession, perhaps outdated,
I can tell you that "Google Sheets" it is a path that I DO NOT advise you to follow.

First, because spreadsheet url being public would allow an attacker to pollute your DB by inserting many rows\records
by simply typing a url in the browser's address bar or creating a simple bot that inserts thousands of lines in a while.

Second, because that set of API do not allow you to implement very sophisticated queries (certainly not at the database level).

If you are really interested in Google Sheets I suggest you check what I have just stated.

If you have to "waste" energy to learn something new
I would suggest you to give priority to SQL and then to a server-side programming language (php, asp.net, node.js)

However, a free space hosting service with php and mySQL support is not too difficult to find.